# Retry processing of failed files in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, file-io, mapreduce, bigdata

I've a Hadoop Map-Reduce program which is nothing but a simple file processing code. Each mapper is having one file as the input.

My Reducer part is empty. All the work is done in map() method.

Now the problem that I'm facing now is -

If the file processing operation failes inside mapper, I'm not able to tell my Hadoop job to wait for some constant seconds before retrying from the same failed file and moving ahead.

Is there any way/configuration to specify as such ?

Let me know if anyone has encountered such use-case.

Comment: Why would waiting fix the issue you had with processing a file? Do you make API calls or something similar?

Comment: Does the task report a failure when it fails? How about mapred.task.timeout (The number of milliseconds before a task will be terminated if it neither reads an input, writes an output, nor updates its status string.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try writing the bad records into different file based on your logic using multiple output. For multiple output you can follow this link : [Multiple output link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html)

If you follow this approach you can filter out badrecords and good records based on your logic in map method and your job will not fail. Using multiple output you can write bad records to a separate file and do analysis on those later. Using this approach you can ensure your job does not fail because of bad records and your good records are processed properly.

You can also look into this link [Counters to detect badrecord](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-8/counters) to figure out how many badrecords you actually have. I hope this helps